# Strange rpath issues with a python3 extension

Tags: python, c, linux

I'm trying to create an extension module in Python. It's a wrapper for an existing C library (.so file)  I'm having rpath issues.

When I do this:

```
rm -rf build
python3 setup.py build_ext --rpath=$ORIGIN
ldd build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/mymodule.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I get this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5aab7000)
libmylibrary.so => not found
libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f38a0a6b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f38a084d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f38a0487000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f38a0283000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f38a007e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f389fd75000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560d8fb8f000)
```

See how libmylibrary.so is not found?

But when I do it like this:

```
rm -rf build
python3 setup.py build_ext
ldd build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/mymodule.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I get this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5aab7000)
libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f38a0a6b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f38a084d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f38a0487000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f38a0283000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f38a007e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f389fd75000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560d8fb8f000)
```

See how libmylibrary.so is missing?

In Python, in either case, cannot locate the 1 wrapped function in libmylibrary.so

It says:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Apr 24 2017, 13:32:13) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mylibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/me/projectx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mylibrary.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: my_special_function
```